# check string contained in a list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, match

What is the best way to check if a string (of ints) is within a list of string?

E.g. Check whether '1' is in (1,2,9,10,11,15)

I had something like:

```
  if(listofString.Contains(radiolist.SelectedValue))
```

where the radiolist.SelectedValue is an integer stored in string form.

I don't think the above would work because the '1' would probably match '11' in the string.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? It does work. `List<T>.Contains` does not special-case `string` and look for substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the array by the `','` character and then using `.Contains()`.

```
string listofString = "1,2,9,10,11,15";
string[] stringInts = listofString.Split(',');

if (stringInts.Contains(radiolist.SelectedValue.ToString()))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming listOfString = "1,2,9,10,11,15"

```
if( listOfString.Split( new char[]{','} ).Any( ss => ss == radioList.SelectedValue ) )
```